# How to do custom shutdown on SIGTERM with Akka?

Tags: akka

By default, Akka shuts down the actor system(s) when it receives a `SIGTERM`. How can I override this behaviour to do my custom shutdown logic before shutting down the akka system? I already have this logic implemented in the actors, using special graceful stop messages - I just need to invoke that logic when the `SIGTERM` is received.

Or do I have to use some other way of shutting down the application? That is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `sys.shutdownHookThread` like this:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  ... initialization code ...
  sys.shutdownHookThread {
    println "Shutting down ..."
    shutdownHandler ! DoSomething
  }
}
```

Comment: Will that definitely run before the actor system is shut down?

Comment: I don't see any documentation that specifically says so, but it works for us.

Comment: Reading the source code and the Javadoc, it looks like there is no guarantee about the order in which shutdown hooks will be run, so no, it won't always run at the right time. For example, in one version of Java it might work, but in another version, the order might change and it might not work. Or, the shutdown hooks might be run simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Would this fit: http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.1.0/#akka.actor.ActorSystem

```
abstract def
registerOnTermination(code: Runnable): Unit
Register a block of code (callback) to run after ActorSystem.shutdown has been issued and all actors in this actor system have been stopped. Multiple code blocks may be registered by calling this method multiple times. The callbacks will be run sequentially in reverse order of registration, i.e. last registration is run first.
Exceptions thrown
a
RejectedExecutionException if the System has already shut down or if shutdown has been initiated.


abstract def
registerOnTermination[T](code: ⇒ T): Unit
Register a block of code (callback) to run after ActorSystem.shutdown has been issued and all actors in this actor system have been stopped. Multiple code blocks may be registered by calling this method multiple times. The callbacks will be run sequentially in reverse order of registration, i.e. last registration is run first.
Exceptions thrown
a
RejectedExecutionException if the System has already shut down or if shutdown has been initiated.
```

Comment: The problem is that the actors will all have been shut down by that point, so I don't think the data that was inside them will be available any more. Hmmm... I suppose I could dump the data to a special object "outside" the actor system in postStop, and then pick up the data from there in the termination callback, but that's kind of awkward. I think changing the script that starts and stops the application to use something other than SIGTERM (e.g. a Linux fifo) is going to be the neatest way to go here.